# jquery .change inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say i have this `code`

**HTML**

```
<select id="id1">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<select id="id2">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<select id="id3">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
$('#id'+[i]).change(function(){
    $("#result"+[i]).html('<p>Number</p>'+[i]);                 
  });
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4wDk/285/)

Different `<select>` `id` and different result `<div>` `id` through loop

I just want, each `<select>` tag change, show the result through the div based on the `id`

Like this:

`<select>` `id1` change to b, then `div1` show b

`<select>` `id2` change to c, then `div2` show c

`<select>` `id3` change to a, then `div3` show a

In my example fiddle, the code i write is not working, can you please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add clases to your `selects`, register event for that class. Do not use loops to register `.change()` events.  `id` attribute **must** be unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var i, j;
$('select').change(function(){    
    i = this.id.slice(2);
    j = this.value;
    $("#result"+i).html('<p>Number: '+j+'</p>');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x4wDk/298/)

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: WHAT THE HELL.. Its work like a charm... Thank you very much for saving my day :).. and thanks for the simple code and the example :)

Answer (score 2):

try this code.

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
$('#id'+i).change((function(a){
            return function()
            {                   
                $("#result"+a).html('<p>Number '+a+'</p>');
            };  
        })(i));   
}
```

and change your `select` elements id to `id1`,`id2`,`id3`

Comment: this is right too.. just need add some code, then.. working too.. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest you should use `data-` attribute of html to pass the related div id to the change event and get that id and change its html.

Try something like following.

```js
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

  $('#id' + [i]).change(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-shouldupdate"));
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-shouldupdate")).html('<p>Number</p>' + $(this).attr("data-shouldupdate"));

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id1" data-shouldupdate="result1">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
<select id="id2" data-shouldupdate="result2">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
<select id="id3" data-shouldupdate="result3">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

Comment: this is working too.. thanks for your alternate answer